# Best Way to persist CLLocationpoints to Parse and then retrieve them

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In my app I am tracking a users run, think map my run or something along those lines. As the user is running an MKPolyline  trails the users position, when the uses finishes the run part of what I need to do is have the "Run"  be saved to parse for others to view.  Right now the MKPolyline is made up  of CLLocation points which are saved into an array

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
for location in locations as! [CLLocation] {

if location.horizontalAccuracy < 20 {
  //update distance
  if self.locations.count > 0 {
    distance += location.distanceFromLocation(self.locations.last)
  }

  self.locations.append(location)
}
}
}
```

I am looking for advice as to the best practice of saving and retrieving this "Run" to parse and then retrieving it and displaying the retrieved data onto a map.

Comment: Are you only going to display it on a map or anything else? How long is a run allowed to be?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array of `PFGeoPoints`.

Parse suggests that you don't store more than 100 objects in an array property of an object, so if you are storing a lot more, you can create a wrapper class that has the GeoPoint property and an identifier, and use a query to retrieve them by identifier.